# Messages not consumed from reply Queue post restarting the Master

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

We are using remote chunking with one master and 2 workers. While testing with small job all chunk messages has been sent to Queue in one go and  then Master went down but workers are continuing to work on chunks from request Queue.
When Master restarted , all the replies from the worker are queued in Reply-Queue but due to miss match in correlation ID of reply messages and new message container created , messages are not consumed from the reply queue.

How to deal with such scenarios while using Spring Batch.

```
 <int-jms:outbound-gateway
        id="masterOutboundGateway"
        connection-factory="masterJMSConnectionFactory"
        correlation-key="JMSCorrelationID"
        request-channel="ChunkMasterRequestChannel"
        request-destination-name="ChunkRequestQueue"
        receive-timeout="50000"
        reply-channel="ChunkMasterReplyChannel"
        reply-destination-name="ChunkReplyQueue" async="true"  >
        <int-jms:reply-listener/>
    </int-jms:outbound-gateway>
```

Comment: When you restart the job, are you restarting the **same** job instance? ie are you passing the same identifying job parameters? Chunk requests and responses are identified by a JobInstanceId and a SequenceNumber, so if the master is restarted correctly (ie within the same job instance), it should pick-up waiting replies from the reply-queue and process them.

Comment: Hi @MahmoudBenHassine, Yes we are restarting the same Job Instance with correct parameters and we could see that restart publishing messages from where it left off. but previous replies has not been consuming. From active MQ we can see that the reply consumer selector correlation Id is changed, hence it is not picking the old message from reply queue. 
Please see below images of activeMQ for reference.

[Initial_ReplyQueuConsumer] https://i.stack.imgur.com/36gvo.png

[Post_Restart_ReplyQueueConsumer] https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKliB.png
Thanks,
Krishna.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I don't know if this is a misconfiguration in the communication middleware or an issue in Spring Batch. We have a remote chunking sample here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/main/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/remotechunking. If you can reproduce the issue with it (by using a JobOperator to stop the job and restart it), the please open an issue and we will look at it in more details. Thank you.